# Local php-mysql install not connecting to remote db?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote database from my local machine, and php is throwing a nice vague error, so I was hoping someone with a bit more experience in this area could point me in the right direction. The error I'm getting:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Connection refused in /my/obfuscated/directory/config.php on line 10
Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: The error message is not *vague*, it's pretty specific. The network connection is refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is "Connection refused". So, remote sever refuse your request.
Try to configure remote server to allow your connection